# How to return a HashSet of a class from a StartActivityforResult in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-contacts, hashset

I'm trying to return a `Set<Person> checkedlist = new HashSet<>();` that contains multiple values from creating a person like

```
Person human = new Person(allcontacts.getName(), allcontacts.getPhone());
```

and then adding that person to it with  `checkedlist.add(PersonVariable);`.

After that, I would like to return the intent with checkedlist (the hashset). I'm not sure if there is an easier method to use or not. What I've attempted to do with the help of someone else is make the `Person` class implement `Serializable`, then I return the intent with `returnIntent.putExtra("result", (Serializable) checkedlist);`

Now I think this is where my app crashes: The `onActivityResult` in the original class

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            Set<Person> myObject = (HashSet) data.getParcelableExtra("result");
            for (Person checkedthem : myObject) {
                    Person human = new Person(checkedthem.getName(), checkedthem.getPhone());
                    persons.add(human);
                    BetterDisplay(human);
            }
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed I had to use a for loop and run through all my different results and contacts, but I'm not sure if there is a better or easier method, or I am unable to do so with a `HashSet` and need to figure out a way to put my data in a different variable to be used by the original class.

**That's where I think the problem is if you need more information then:**

First, here is the method that ends the popup class in full if you need it

```
public void registerDoneClick(View view) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    Set<Person> checkedlist = new HashSet<>();

    for (Person allcontacts : list) {
        if(allcontacts.isSelected()) {
            Person checkedthem = new Person(allcontacts.getName(), allcontacts.getPhone());
            checkedlist.add(checkedthem);
        }
    }

    returnIntent.putExtra("result", (Serializable) checkedlist);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Second, the list variable is created in the beginning of the class as `ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();` and populated with:

```
try {
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);` `while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Person allcontacts = new Person(name, phoneNumber);
        list.add(allcontacts);
    }
    phones.close();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Finally, I receive all the checkboxes through the `listAdapter` by checking

```
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        cb.setTag(position);

        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            currentperson.setSelected(true);
        }
```

and the whole method is

```
public class myListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    public myListAdapter() {
        super(SelectContactsActivity.this, R.layout.da_item, list);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.da_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Find person wot work with
        Person currentperson = list.get(position);

        // Fill the view
        TextView nameboxview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
        nameboxview.setText(currentperson.getName());

        TextView numberboxview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NumberView);
        numberboxview.setText(currentperson.getPhone());
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        cb.setTag(position);

        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            currentperson.setSelected(true);
        }


        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while. Thank you!

Comment: Parcelable and Serializable are different interfaces, HashSet is Serializable

Comment: That seems to fix it! now I've run into another problem with the list view but Ill figure that out @EvgeniyStrepetov